# Are inactive triggers counted against test coverage?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

We are in process of deploying a project to PROD and found that test coverage is coming up less then 75%.

There are some triggers we have merged into single trigger.

Question is: whether the inactive triggers are calculated to get average test coverage ?

Documentation says that Comments and @isTest are not counted against coverage. What about inactive triggers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The inactive triggers are counted against code coverage for sure and also there is no way to get coverage for these as this is considered dead code if its not used .

One work around could be to activate these triggers if this has to be kept for future process and use custom setting to decide to run at run time or stop them .

If these are inactive  and no more needed archive this and store code in some repo and get rid of them from production .

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Inactive triggers are counted against code coverage. Possible workarounds:

1. You can comment the trigger body
2. Create test class for inactive trigger so that when you want to activate it you will not run into    code coverage issues
3. Have a custom setting (boolean field) that determines whether the
   logic inside the trigger need to execute. So that you can keep the
   trigger active and you need to have a test class for this.

Hope this helps!!