# Workbench Rest Explorer Apex Code Coverage Query - Wrong Results

Tags: code

I ran a query in REST Explorer ( on ApexCodeCoverage ). Im getting duplicate (and wrong) results.  Few classes/triggeres are repeated with different results.

A class ApplicationInfoHelper is being repeated many times in the results, with different lines (un)covered results.  Same with many other classes in these results.

Atleast the lines covered/uncovered should be same, even if the class is repeating.  [Note the Ids are the same, so I'm sure it is the same class]

Answer (score 5):

[ApexCodeCoverage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexcodecoverage.htm) has a row per test method. If you were to add `TestMethodName` to your SOQL query you would see the test case that is responsible for the NumLinesCovered.

NumLinesCovered and NumLinesUncovered vary as each test method touches different lines.

You can drill further down to Coverage to see specifically which lines were hit and which weren't.

---

Instead you might want to use the SOQL queries that the developer console does:

[ApexCodeCoverageAggregate](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexcodecoverageaggregate.htm) - Represents aggregate code coverage test results for an Apex class or trigger.

> SELECT ApexClassOrTriggerId, ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate  WHERE ApexClassOrTriggerId != NULL AND ApexClassOrTrigger.Name != NULL AND (NumLinesCovered > 0 OR NumLinesUncovered > 0) AND NumLinesCovered != NULL AND NumLinesUncovered != NULL ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name

[ApexOrgWideCoverage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexorgwidecoverage.htm) - Represents code coverage test results for an entire organization.

> SELECT PercentCovered FROM ApexOrgWideCoverage

**Note: both of these SOQL queries are against the tooling API.**

Comment: Its not SOQL I guess.  I get the error " sObject type 'ApexOrgWideCoverage' is not supported"  I will try in REST Explorer

Comment: @BruceLee It is SOQL, I've successfully executed both queries *against the tooling API*.

Comment: How can I run this query in the workbench?

Comment: @abhi I don't think you can directly run a SOQL query against the Tooling API in the Workbench SOQL Query tool. Instead you could use the REST Explorer under utilities. The Developer Console and the [Fuse IT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) both support SOQL against the Tooling API.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the Developer Console doesn't support exporting the records to a csv file.

Comment: @abhi The FuseIT SFDC Explorer can run the SOQL query against the Tooling API and then export the results to CSV.

Comment: @DanielBallinger
I just downloaded this tool. I am getting some errors. I sent an email with the error to the support team.

Comment: Also we need add a condition to avoid all inactive triggers and classes to have  more granular count.
```SELECT ApexClassOrTriggerId, ApexClassOrTrigger.Name, NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate WHERE ApexClassOrTriggerId != NULL AND ApexClassOrTrigger.Name != NULL AND (NumLinesCovered > 0 OR NumLinesUncovered > 0) AND NumLinesCovered != NULL AND NumLinesUncovered != NULL AND ApexClassOrTrigger.IsActive = TRUE ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name ```

Comment: @Giene According to [Are inactive triggers counted against test coverage?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/53061/102) triggers are still counted when inactive, so you might not want to exclude them.

Comment: Wanted to add for those who may come across this thread, in the WHERE clause, "ApexClassOrTrigger.IsActive = TRUE" will make the query return only triggers, and will filter out all apex classes as of API v.48.0 (Spring '20)

Comment: @JamesQuinn Have you raised a support case for that yet? I can confirm that adding `ApexClassOrTrigger.IsActive = true` to the where clause only brings back triggers. Even when the Apex classes have an active status. The API version doesn't seem to change the result.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I haven't raised a case. Wasn't sure if this was intended functionality or not, but just wanted to state that clearly for anyone who might read this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing this result because different tests are covering different parts of the class. If you either specific a specific testclass ID, or a specific Class ID, you should get the consolidated value.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with the Salesforce Inspector Chrome Extension

1. Install the [Salesforce Inspector Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh?hl=en)
2. From an SFDC window, click on the caret on the right side of screen to open the inspector
3. Put the query in the query editor (sorry, still can't get the name of the class), and make sure use tooling api is selected

   ```
   SELECT ApexClassOrTriggerId,  NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered
   FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
   WHERE ApexClassOrTriggerId != NULL
   AND ApexClassOrTrigger.Name != NULL
   AND (NumLinesCovered > 0 OR NumLinesUncovered > 0)
   AND NumLinesCovered != NULL
   AND NumLinesUncovered != NULL
   ORDER BY ApexClassOrTrigger.Name
   ```
4. Click export and choose your format.