# Inactive Trigger Test Code Question for potential solution

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I was reading this:
[Are inactive triggers counted against test coverage?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53061/are-inactive-triggers-counted-against-test-coverage)

And I had an idea pop into my head: Can I cover several apex triggers, using a single test function, if they all contain the same code to be tested?

Here is my reasoning: my manager has asked me to please not delete the inactive apex triggers, and to instead comment out the code. But I am still tasked with getting coverage on these.

The idea I had was to use a hidden checkbox field, and assert that it is checked for the actual test.

The idea is if every trigger has the exact same code, would that single test asserting the checkbox checked as true satisfy the test coverage for all of those triggers?

Something like:

```
List<ObjectType> toUpdate = new List<ObjectType>();
for(ObjectType test : Trigger.new){
    if(name == value) check the checkbox;
}

test class
Insert test account to trigger the trigger;

TestStart();
Assert Checkbox
TestStop();
```

Would I run into any issues testing things this way? Would it cause problems to populate the triggers with the same code after commenting out the main code blocks?

Comment: Your boss sounds kinda clueless.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It's more his boss that is. His boss is the "We don't want to get rid of anything in case we need it in the future" type of person. We're trying to come up with a solution that'll let us get coverage while also satisfy that. (It's not my call, otherwise I would just save all the triggers in cls and trigger files, then store them in our team network folder, and remove them from Salesforce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, implement `Version Control` and get rid of *everything* you don't use any more. You can restore it at will very simply. But, that might be a bit of a pick your battles situation, and involves an unfortunate amount of office politics.

So what to do? This situation illustrates the value of a trigger framework. Then you can just comment out the method calls and not worry about the trigger body; the lines will get hit anyway. Here is the pattern I use, and your trigger coverage would be essentially unaffected in this scenario:

**Service Layer**

```
public with sharing class LeadServices
{
    public static void methodNoLongerNeeded1(List<Lead> leads) { /* implementation */ }
    public static void methodNoLongerNeeded2(List<Lead> leads) { /* implementation */ }
}
```

**Handler Pattern**

```
public with sharing class LeadTriggerHandler
{
    @TestVisible static void bypassTrigger = false;

    final List<Lead> newRecords;
    final Map<Id, Lead> oldMap;
    public LeadTriggerHandler(List<Lead> newRecords, Map<Id, Lead> oldMap)
    {
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }

    public void beforeInsert()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;
        methodNoLongerNeeded1(newRecords);
    }
    public void afterInsert()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;
        methodNoLongerNeeded2(newRecords);
    }

    public void beforeUpdate() { /* implementation */ }
    public void afterUpdate() { /* implementation */ }

    public void beforeDelete() { /* implementation */ }
    public void afterDelete() { /* implementation */ }

    public void afterUndelete() { /* implementation */ }
}
```

**Trigger Implementation**

```
trigger Lead on Lead (before insert, after insert /*etc*/)
{
    LeadTriggerHandler handle = new LeadTriggerHandler(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert) handle.beforeInsert();
        if (trigger.isUpdate) handle.beforeUpdate();
        if (trigger.isDelete) handle.beforeDelete();
    }
    if (trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert) handle.afterInsert();
        if (trigger.isUpdate) handle.afterUpdate();
        if (trigger.isDelete) handle.afterDelete();
        if (trigger.isUndelete) handle.afterUndelete();
    }
}
```

Getting coverage on your trigger itself is now *trivial*. It's also easy to just comment out `methodNoLongerNeeded1` if that is all you were doing in some trigger you want to deactivate. One Trigger Per Object.

Comment: This is a lot more efficient than what I was thinking about. I'll fight for version control, as that would make a huge difference if we were using it. In the meantime I'll study this trigger framework example, and work on implementing it. I appreciate the information a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Notice too the `bypassTrigger` flag. Not relevant to coverage, but when you are trying to test your `Service Layer`, it makes it a lot easier to verify the `Apex Class` is where the work is being done, not the `Apex Trigger`.